# nsis refresh environment during setup

Tags: nsis

During my setup i install redistributables. After installing my program i want to execute the program during the setup. For that the redistributables are needed. But the environment is not refreshed during setup, so i can't start the program. Can i refresh the environtment during the setup, or reread the environment? Or read the system environment which has changed after the redistributable installation?

I need the environment changes made during the installation of the redistributables during the setup.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to refresh a custom variable or are you talking about %Path%?

Comment: I'm talking about %Path%.

Comment: Refreshing %Path% is tricky because it is stored in two places in the registry and you need to be careful so you don't exceed the NSIS string length limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same issue, that I solved with a workaround, but I came across this solution and I would like to share with you.

This should reload environment variables during setup:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh
!ifndef NSIS_CHAR_SIZE
    !define NSIS_CHAR_SIZE 1
    !define SYSTYP_PTR i
!else
    !define SYSTYP_PTR p
!endif
!ifndef ERROR_MORE_DATA
    !define ERROR_MORE_DATA 234
!endif
/*!ifndef KEY_READ
    !define KEY_READ 0x20019
!endif*/

Function RegReadExpandStringAlloc
    System::Store S
    Pop $R2 ; reg value
    Pop $R3 ; reg path
    Pop $R4 ; reg hkey
    System::Alloc 1 ; mem
    StrCpy $3 0 ; size

    loop:
        System::Call 'SHLWAPI::SHGetValue(${SYSTYP_PTR}R4,tR3,tR2,i0,${SYSTYP_PTR}sr2,*ir3r3)i.r0' ; NOTE: Requires SHLWAPI 4.70 (IE 3.01+ / Win95OSR2+)
        ${If} $0 = 0
            Push $2
            Push $0
        ${Else}
            System::Free $2
            ${If} $0 = ${ERROR_MORE_DATA}
                IntOp $3 $3 + ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE} ; Make sure there is room for SHGetValue to \0 terminate
                System::Alloc $3
                Goto loop
            ${Else}
                Push $0
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
    System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Function RefreshProcessEnvironmentPath
    System::Store S
    Push ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER}
    Push "Environment"
    Push "Path"
    Call RegReadExpandStringAlloc
    Pop $0

    ${IfThen} $0 <> 0 ${|} System::Call *(i0)${SYSTYP_PTR}.s ${|}
    Pop $1
    Push ${HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE}
    Push "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
    Push "Path"
    Call RegReadExpandStringAlloc
    Pop $0

    ${IfThen} $0 <> 0 ${|} System::Call *(i0)${SYSTYP_PTR}.s ${|}
    Pop $2
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrlen(t)(${SYSTYP_PTR}r1)i.R1'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrlen(t)(${SYSTYP_PTR}r2)i.R2'
    System::Call '*(&t$R2 "",&t$R1 "",i)${SYSTYP_PTR}.r0' ; The i is 4 bytes, enough for a ';' separator and a '\0' terminator (Unicode)
    StrCpy $3 ""

    ${If} $R1 <> 0
    ${AndIf} $R2 <> 0
        StrCpy $3 ";"
    ${EndIf}

    System::Call 'USER32::wsprintf(${SYSTYP_PTR}r0,t"%s%s%s",${SYSTYP_PTR}r2,tr3,${SYSTYP_PTR}r1)?c'
    System::Free $1
    System::Free $2
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t"PATH",${SYSTYP_PTR}r0)'
    System::Free $0
    System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Section
    Call RefreshProcessEnvironmentPath
SectionEnd
```

Source: http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=3028153&postcount=12